# @MockBean with Junit Jupiter concurrent mode

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, junit-jupiter

I am trying to use

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default=concurrent
```

along with @MockBean from Spring Boot. However, the tests starts to fail when I set to concurrent mode. I tried setting

```
@MockBean(reset = MockReset.NONE)
```

However, it also does not help. Seems like mocked bean is reinitialized / reset even though MockReset.NONE is set.
Is that possible to use @MockBean allow with concurrent mode or is it a known limitation?

Bean I am mocking:

```java
@Service
public class SampleService {

  public Mono<String> processCall(String call) {
    return Mono.just("ok");
  }

}
```

The controller I am testing:

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SampleController {

  private final SampleService sampleService;

  @PostMapping("/call")
  public Mono<String> processCall(@RequestBody String body) {
    return sampleService.processCall(body);
  }

}
```

And tests:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(SampleController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SampleController.class})
class SampleTest {

  @MockBean(reset = MockReset.NONE)
  private SampleService sampleService;

  @Autowired
  private WebTestClient webTestClient;

  @Test
  void givenSampleServiceWorksFineExpectOkResponse() {
    String randomBody = "1234";
    when(sampleService.processCall(randomBody)).thenReturn(Mono.just("ok"));

    callService(randomBody).expectStatus().isOk().expectBody(String.class).isEqualTo("ok");
  }

  @Test
  void givenSampleServiceFailedExpectErrorResponse() {
    String randomBody = "9876";
    when(sampleService.processCall(randomBody))
        .thenReturn(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("error")));

    callService(randomBody).expectStatus().is5xxServerError();
  }

  private ResponseSpec callService(String body) {
    return webTestClient
        .post()
        .uri(
            uriBuilder ->
                uriBuilder
                    .path("/call")
                    .build())
        .bodyValue(body)
        .exchange();
  }

}
```

I set concurrent mode for Jupiter in file junit-platform.properties:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default=concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=dynamic
```

Comment: Can you please post the error message you are getting? Please further provide the name of the file where you added the config line. Finally, please provide the entire Junit class so that we get the situation better

Comment: Question updated with minimal working example. When tests are run not concurrent or manually one by one all works fine.

Comment: The mock is a singleton because it is part of the application context. As it is a singleton only 1 behaviour at a time will/can be active.

Comment: I thought one behaviour per method call with specific arguments

Comment: You can check how to add syntax highlighting to your code in the question here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help :-)

Comment: The behaviour is registered on a singleton. Hence depending on the order it might or might not work. If you run it a 100 times it might succeed once depending on the order, speed etc.

Comment: But when I say do A in case method is called with A param and do B in case method is call with B param then both should work in parallel

Comment: If the bodies differ yes. One thing is that you only need the `@WebFluxTest` to other annotations can be removed (`@WebFluxTest` is meta annotated and you don't need `@ContextConfiguration` as that is implied already).

Comment: So in the example I gave bodies are different